# Using Find() with conditional that have the first letter "AA" in c#

Tags: c#, find, substring

it is possible to find some data by using this condition "that have the first letter A"

here is how i use find() to find id_cart that equal with the input

```
var store = await _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart == entity.id_cart).ToListAsync();
```

but i want to change it to be like this, but i dont know how

```
string key = "ID";
var store = await _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart "that have the first character" key).ToListAsync();
```

is it possible ? how should i do it ?

Comment: Please provide one example with expected output.

Comment: thank you for your attention, the question has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.StartsWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_),

```
string key = "ID";
var store = await _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart.StartsWith(key)).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

In c# and .Net there is a method called StartsWith() which returns a boolean.

Source docks: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0

```
var store = await _cartCollection.Find(x => x.id_cart.StartsWith(key)).ToListAsync();
```

If you want to ignore case sensitive just use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`
I usually use the `Where()` just because it's similar to SQL statement and more readable. Hope it solves.